# Regex that matches before and after certain characters

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to craft a delimiter regex (for use with java.util.Scanner) that segments a string on whitespace, as well as keeping colons, opening parenthesis and closing parenthesis as separate tokens. That is, `foo(a:b)` should segment into the tokens `foo`, `(`, `a`, `:`, `b` and `)`.

My current best effort is the pattern `"\\s+|(?=[(:])|(?<=[:)])"` which for some reason I can't understand fails to match after the opening parenthesis and before the closing parenthesis, but matches fine on both sides of the colon.

Comment: Try `\s+|(?=[():])|(?<=[:(])` https://regex101.com/r/9pSfWr/1

Comment: It seems you just need to include both parentheses into the character classes, `"\\s+|(?=[():])|(?<=[:()])"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all those separate parts, you could extend the character classes asserting one of the characters `[(:)]` at the left and, if this is the whole string, assert one of the characters `[(:]` at the right.

If you also want to match the position after the last closing parenthesis, both character classes can be the same `[(:)]`

```
\s+|(?=[(:)])|(?<=[(:])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TKOcmp/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/7Jquon)

Example code

```
String s = "foo(a:b)";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s).useDelimiter("\\s+|(?=[(:)])|(?<=[(:])");
while(scanner.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

Output

```
foo
(
a
:
b
)
```